# where can I find ./configure to run the command ./configure –with-zlib=/usr/include in python 3.2

Tags: python-3.x, ubuntu-11.04

Based on this [zlib-install-on-python](http://www.1stbyte.com/2005/06/26/configure-and-compile-python-with-zlib/), I need to run the following command

```
./configure –with-zlib=/usr/include
```

Question: Where can I find the configure in python 3.2?

> user@ubuntu:~$ ls /usr/include/z* /usr/include/zconf.h 
>   /usr/include/zlibdefs.h  /usr/include/zlib.h

```
user@ubuntu:~/Downloads/Python-3.2$ ./configure –with-zlib=/usr/include
configure: error: invalid variable name: `–with-zlib'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to run `./configure` in your python install directory.  This is wherever you unpacked the source tarball.

```
cd /path/to/python3.2
./configure --with-zlib=/usr/include
```

Notice that the `--with-zlib` argument is prefixed with two dashes, not one.

**EDIT:**
From `./configure -h`,

> --with-PACKAGE[=ARG]    use PACKAGE [ARG=yes]

After trying `./configure --with-zlib=yes`, which also produces the error, I think `PACKAGE` might be a non-standard package.  However, to solve your problem (making sure python has zlib), you should just be able to do `./configure; make; sudo make install`.  You show that you have `zlib.h`, so this should reinstall python with support for zlib.  I'll see if I can find anymore info on the `--with-PACKAGE` option, but this should solve the root issue.

Comment: it doesn't work for me. it seems that it is invalid. please see my updated post.

Comment: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-zlib

Comment: Your answer solve my part of my question and it seems that the option is not a valid one though. Not your fault:)